# Get string from JSXAttrValue (swc)

Tags: rust, swc-compiler

I am creating a SWC plugin using rust. I have a [JSXAttrValue](https://rustdoc.swc.rs/swc_core/ecma/utils/swc_ecma_ast/enum.JSXAttrValue.html) enum. How to get a string from it?

```rust
fn visit_mut_jsx_attr_value(&mut self, n: &mut JSXAttrValue) {
    let value = ?????;        
}
```

I need the ability to compare "value" with a string or write to a file.

The same question on the [rust forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/get-string-from-jsxattrvalue-enum/92932).

Comment: What kind of string do you want to retrieve? Could you provide some examples of input and output?